# Set any one of the delegate method is @required

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am having a protocol in which I have two methods as follows.

```
@protocol ActionPerformerDelegate <NSObject>

@required

    - (void)actionCompleted;
    - (void)actionCompletedWithMessage:(NSString *)message;

@end
```

If a class confirms to this protocol, that class should implement at least one of these methods. I know about *@required* and *@optional* keywords. If I use @required, Xcode warns me to implement both the methods. If I use @optional Xcode doesn't warn me to implement any of the methods. How to specify that implementing any one of the methods alone is necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Protocol methods are either required or optional; what you're asking for cannot be checked at compile time. You could however mark both methods as optional and check which your delegate implements at runtime. Something similar to the following:

```
// In ActionPerformer.m.
SEL selector = @selector(actionCompletedWithMessage:);
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:selector]) {
  // ...
} else if ([[self.delegate class] respondsToSelector:selector]) {
  // ...
} else {
  [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:@"delegate doesn't "
       "implement actionCompletedWithMessage:."];
}
```